# Error: AttributeError: Movie instance has no attribute 'show_trailer'

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, indentation

I made first folder for Class Movie:

```
import webbrowser

class Movie():
    def __init__(self,movie_title,movie_storyline,poster_image,trailer_youtube):
        self.title=movie_title
        self.storyline=movie_storyline
        self.poster_image_url=poster_image
        self.trailer=trailer_youtube

def show_trailer(self):
    webbrowser.open(self.trailer)
```

Then in another file, I am trying to call the function:

```
import media

toy_story= media.Movie("toy_story","a boy who have toys","http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114709/mediaviewer/rm3813007616","http://www.imdb.com/videoplayer/vi2052129305?playlistId=tt0114709&ref_=tt_ov_vi")


avatar=media.Movie("Avatar","A marine on an alien planet","http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/mediaviewer/rm843615744","http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/videoplayer/vi531039513?ref_=tt_ov_vi")
avatar.show_trailer()
```

But, I am getting below error:

`AttributeError: Movie instance has no attribute 'show_trailer'`

Any suggesions?

Comment: Fix your formatting. Make sure your method show_trailer() is indented inside the class and not just in the same file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your indentation is wrong for your class `Movie`. I cant reproduce the problem with the following 2 files in the same folder - perhaps your method is not correctly indented to be part of the class:

**media.py**

```
import webbrowser

class Movie():
    def __init__(self,movie_title,movie_storyline,poster_image,trailer_youtube):
        self.title = movie_title
        self.storyline = movie_storyline
        self.poster_image_url = poster_image
        self.trailer = trailer_youtube

    def show_trailer(self):
        print(self.trailer)
```

**test.py**

```
import media

toy_story=media.Movie("toy_story",
                      "a boy who have toys",
                      "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114709/mediaviewer/rm3813007616",
                      "http://www.imdb.com/videoplayer/vi2052129305?playlistId=tt0114709&ref_=tt_ov_vi")

avatar=media.Movie("Avatar",
                   "A marine on an alien planet",
                   "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/mediaviewer/rm843615744",
                   "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/videoplayer/vi531039513?ref_=tt_ov_vi")

avatar.show_trailer()
```

Output:

```
>> http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/videoplayer/vi531039513?ref_=tt_ov_vi
>> Process finished with exit code 0
```